# Django : Form in forms.py does not displayed in HTML

Tags: python, html, django, forms

I've been trying to render HTML using form I made in forms.py, however this is not working, just fail to loaded without error message. Also, there is no message in console too, so I'm having hard time to fix this. Please take a look and tell me which part is wrong.

This is urls.py

```
url(r'^profile/(?P<username>[-\w.]+)/$', views.profile, name='profile'),
url(r'^password_change/(?P<username>[-\w.]+)/$', views.password_change, name='password_change'),
url(r'^password_change_done/$', views.password_change_done, name='password_change_done'),
```

forms.py

```
class PasswordChangeForm(forms.Form):
    oldpassword = forms.CharField(max_length = 20, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'type':'password', 'placeholder':'your old Password',  'class' : 'span'}))
    newpassword1 = forms.CharField(max_length = 20, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'type':'password', 'placeholder':'New Password',  'class' : 'span'}))
    newpassword2 = forms.CharField(max_length = 20, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'type':'password', 'placeholder':'Confirm New Password',  'class' : 'span'}))

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ("username",)
        field_classes = {'username': UsernameField}

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if self._meta.model.USERNAME_FIELD in self.fields:
            self.fields[self._meta.model.USERNAME_FIELD].widget.attrs.update({'autofocus': True})

    def clean(self):
        if 'newpassword1' in self.cleaned_data and 'newpassword2' in self.cleaned_data:
            if self.cleaned_data['newpassword1'] != self.cleaned_data['newpassword2']:
                raise forms.ValidationError(_("The two password fields did not match."))
            return self.cleaned_data 

    def save(self, commit=True):
        user = super().save(commit=False)
        user.set_password(self.cleaned_data["password1"])
        if commit:
            user.save()
        return user
```

views.py

```
@login_required
def password_change(request, username):
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = PasswordChangeForm(data=request.POST, user=request.user)
    print("username is "+username)

    if form.is_valid():
        #form.save()
        update_session_auth_hash(request, form.user)
        form.save()
        print("A")
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/blog/password_change_done/') 
    else:
        update_session_auth_hash(request, form.user)
        form.save()
        print("B")
        return redirect(reverse('blog:profile', args=[form.user.get_username()]))
else:
    print("C")
    form = PasswordChangeForm(user=request.user)#unbound
    return redirect(reverse('blog:profile', args=[form.user.get_username()]))
```

profile.html (where password_change should be loaded.)

```
<h2>password change</h2>
{% if error_message %}
<p><strong>{{ error_message }}</strong></p>
{% else %}
{% endif %}
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" action="{% url 'blog:password_change' user.username %}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <button type="submit" class="button-primary">password change</button></div>
</form>
```

Comment: can you see all the rest of the page? only this form is not loaded?

Comment: @AlexanderTyapkov rest of the page is correctly loaded, I guess it is because other parts are built up with HTML. Only this form is not loaded.

Comment: you are not providing form to the template, have you seen in your view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one of the examples how change_password view can be implemented

```
from django.contrib import messages
from django.contrib.auth import update_session_auth_hash
from django.contrib.auth.forms import PasswordChangeForm
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect

def change_password(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = PasswordChangeForm(request.user, request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            user = form.save()
            update_session_auth_hash(request, user)  # Important!
            messages.success(request, 'Your password was successfully updated!')
            return redirect('accounts:change_password')
        else:
            messages.error(request, 'Please correct the error below.')
    else:
        form = PasswordChangeForm(request.user)
    return render(request, 'accounts/change_password.html', {
        'form': form
    })
```

Have a look at the part related to GET request. There you have to create the form and render the page with context. You should provide form to the context.

In your case you create the form and redirect to the profile page straight after that. That is why you see empty form page.

Comment: This password_change form should be in the profile,url. I'm trying to load two forms in one html. Is it impossible??

Comment: @camila it is possible, but you are not providing form to the template..have a look a the last line of the code I have provided. There I have form which is given to change_password.html